# jQuery remove item from a space delimited data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html, custom-data-attribute

Given this markup:

```
<a data-foo="bar baz">Hello</a>
```

Is it possible to remove `baz` but keep `bar`, ideally without removing both then adding back `bar`.

The jQuery `removeData` method appears to remove the specified data attribute or all data attributes.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: @Johan another brain fart, sorry. It's a space separated list. Quesiton updated.

Comment: @Satpal question fixed.

Comment: @Anton it don't know what `bar` is going to be. So I can't remove it and then set it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
 $('a').data('foo', $('a').data('foo').split(' ')[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure this is what you're looking for, but this may help

1. First get the data-foo values

   `var foo = $('a').data('foo')`
2. Split the `foo` string to an array

   `var foos = []`

   `foos = foo.split(" ")`
3. Pick the items you want to keep (or remove the items you want to remove)

   `var index = foos.indexOf("baz")`

   `foos.splice(index,1)`
4. Put the string back together with only the left foos

   `var foo = foos.join(" ")`
5. Set the data-foo to the new filtered one

   `$('a').data('foo',foo)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming data is a space delimited string:

```
var data = $("a").data("foo");
data = (" " + data + " ").replace(" baz ", " ").replace(/^ | $/g, "");
$("a").data("foo", data);
```

This should work for `foo baz`, `baz foo`, `foo baz bar`, etc.